# Не видит первый элемент массива в функции

Tags: c, массивы, функции

помогите понять, почему функции **masivY** и **masivZ** , не видят первый элемент массива, из-за этого дальше не правильно считают. Спасибо

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

    //Формирование массива У с положительными
    int masivY(int a[],int n, int b[], int n2)
    {
    int j=0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i]>0){
            b[j]=a[i]; 
        if (n2!=j) j++;
                    }
    }
    printf("\n\n Массив Y с положительными:\n ");
    for (int i=0; i<j; i++) printf("%d ",b[i]);
    }   
    
    //Формирование массива Z с отрицательными
    int masivZ(int a[],int n, int b[], int n2)
    {
    int j=0;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        if (a[i]<0){
            b[j]=a[i]; 
        if (n2!=j) j++;
                    }
    printf("\n\n Массив Z с отрицательными:\n ");
    for (int i=0; i<j; i++) printf("%d ",b[i]);
    }

    //ФУНКЦИЯ ПОИСКА МАКС ЭЛЕМЕНТА
    int poiskmax(int a[], int n)
    {
    int max=a[0], i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    if(abs(a[i])>max)
    max=a[i];
    }
    printf("\n Максимальный по модулю элемент : %d",max);
    }

    //ФУНКЦИЯ УДАЛЕНИЯ 1ого элемента
    int udal1(int a[], int n)
    {
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
    a[i]=a[i+1];
    }
    n--;
    printf("\n После удаления 1ого элемента ");
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }

int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "RUS");
    
    int n;
    printf("Укажите размер массива:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int x[n],m=0, q=0;
    
    //ввод массива
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    printf("Введите элемент №%d:\n",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&x[i]);
    if (x[i]<0) m++;
    if (x[i]>0) q++;
         }

    int z[m],y[q];  
    //Вывод массива         
    printf("Ваш массив:\n");
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    printf("%d ",x[i]);
    poiskmax(x,n);
    udal1(x,n);
    
    //Y
    masivY(x,n,y,q);
    poiskmax(y,q);
    udal1(y,q);
    
    //Z
    masivZ(x,n,z,m);
    poiskmax(z,m);
    udal1(z,m);
    //printf("\n");
   
    
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Результат]

Comment: В чем неправильность (что значит "не видят")? Как вы хотите, чтоб работало?

Comment: @Harry Я ввожу элементы с клавиатуры, вверху видно, что я ввел элмент номер1 (-1), а внизу в "Массив Z с отрицательными" его нет, результат этого обрабатывают фун-ии masivY и masivZ . Тоже самое будет если первое будет положительное. Спасибо

Comment: Они их видят. Просто Вы удаляете первый элемент. Вы выводите Ваш массив, потом ищете максимальный по модулю элемент, а потом удаляете первый элемент. (блок "Вывод массива", строки 77-81)

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("Ваш массив:\n");
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
printf("%d ",x[i]);
poiskmax(x,n);
```

Тут массив `x` со всеми элементами

```
udal1(x,n);
```

Тут он без первого элемента

```
...


//Z
masivZ(x,n,z,m);
```

Тут `z` делается из массива `x` без этой -1...

```
poiskmax(z,m);
udal1(z,m);
```

Вот и все.

Comment: спасибо большое! Плюс поставил